# How can I "watch" multiple source directories in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'm pretty sure I've seen in Jekyll blog projects with multiple source document directories, such as `_posts` and `_pages`, but the `source` parameter in the `_config.yml` file can only take 1 directory as its argument, and neither an array nor a space separated string of directories works.

Am I misunderstanding the meaning of the `source` parameter? I'm expecting it to be used by watch to specify which files' changes will trigger a build, and which files to build.

Also, I have fragments such as `about.md` which can be included in other pages. What is the best location for files like this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `source` configuration refers to your `<project_root>`, not individual directories within the project root. By default, its set to your current_directory (the location from where you are running `jekyll build (or) serve`.

Jekyll watches all nested files and directories deep within the source directory by default.

`about.md` is not meant to be seen as a fragment to be included in other files. Its a full-blown "page" that would render into `_site/about.html` or `_site/about/index.html` depending on your permalink settings.

Fragments to be included in other pages live inside the `_includes` directory and are inserted via the Liquid construct `{% include <fragment-filename>.html %}`

Other than `_layouts`, `_includes` and `_sass`, directories that start with an underscore are ignored by Jekyll unless you *configure* Jekyll to see them as "collections". `_posts` is a pre-defined and hard-coded collection directory.

For more information on Jekyll, refer the official documentation at https://jekyllrb.com

Answer (score 0):

If anyone, like me, is looking to include several source folders in **github-pages**, you can simply configure the jekyll root in github-page on the `master` branch. I.e. not on `gh-page` branch, nor on the `docs` folder.

Thus, all folder is processed. `README.md` are treated as `index.md` and you can easily make relative links from the main `README.md` at the root to any other doc which are "below" it in the file hierarchy. Thus having jekyll cover all your code documentation.